# Using Django and Python to read in file in views.py and exporting the tab dilimited file to a HTML table?

Tags: python, html, django, tabs, csv

I am new to Django and Python and was wondering how I could read a tab dilimited file into a html table by modifying my views.py and then returning the separate columns as a variable and returning that variable through params and then changing my template.html page.

so for example

```
 def index(request):  
    myfile = open (filename.txt)

   for row in myfile:
       list = row.rstrip().split('\t')

       params = {
       "first" = list[0]
       }

       return render(request, 'index.html', params)
```

something of this sort any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is to use `with` to open files:

`with open('filename.ext', 'mode') as f:`

Using `with` automagically **closes** your file for you so you don't have to explicitly do so :)

Second, please visit: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#examples for a great explanation from the source.

The first example demos how to read your CSV file!

Comment: My pleasure!  Glad you were able to figure it out :)